# CvException warpAffine rotate frames

Tags: android, opencv, rotation, video-streaming

Good morning to all.
I am developing an Android application.
I receive this exception in the logcat:

```
 06-16 11:42:41.726: WARN/dalvikvm(11429): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e61ac8)
 06-16 11:42:41.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11429): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2473
    CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: /home/reports/ci/slave/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:3272: error: (-215) src.cols > 0 && src.rows > 0 in function void cv::warpAffine(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::Size, int, int, const Scalar&)
    ]
    at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.warpAffine_2(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.warpAffine(Imgproc.java:9114)
    at com.micaela.myapp.MainActivity.manageRotation(MainActivity.java:416)
    at com.micaela.myapp.MainActivity.chooseMode(MainActivity.java:374)
    at com.micaela.myapp.MainActivity.onCameraFrame(MainActivity.java:344)
    at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:381)
    at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:323)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

My application opens a video stream, using the object JavaCameraView, and captures frames from it, and before showing them on screen, they are properly rotated basing on the orientation of the device. For this purpose I use warpAffine function of the OpenCv4Android libraries, in the 2.4.5 version.

The method in which I call this function is:

```
public void manageRotation(Mat matrix, Display display) {

    int screenOrientation = display.getRotation();

    Point center =new Point(matrix.cols()/2,matrix.rows()/2);
    int angle = 0; //default
    double scale = 1.0;

    Mat rotImage;

    switch (screenOrientation){
        default:
        case ORIENTATION_0: // Portrait
            if (mOpenCvCameraView.getCameraId() == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                angle=90;
                rotImage = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, scale);
                Imgproc.warpAffine(matrix, matrix, rotImage, matrix.size());
            } else{
                angle=-90;
                rotImage = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, scale);
                Imgproc.warpAffine(matrix, matrix, rotImage, matrix.size());
            }
            break;
        case ORIENTATION_90: // Landscape right
            angle = 180;
            rotImage = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, scale);
            Imgproc.warpAffine(matrix, matrix, rotImage, matrix.size());
            break;
        case ORIENTATION_180:  //Reverse portrait
            angle = 270;
            rotImage = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, scale);
            Imgproc.warpAffine(matrix, matrix, rotImage, matrix.size());
            break;
        case ORIENTATION_270: // Landscape left
            break;
    }

}
```

I call this method in OnCameraFrame, after capturing frame, passing it as parameter.
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important thing to remember about OpenCV errors is that they're the opposite of what they mean, since they represent failed assertions.  So the error

```
src.cols > 0 && src.rows > 0
```

actually means that one or both of the dimensions of the source matrix are 0.  This likely means that your `Mat matrix` has 0 rows and 0 columns.  Since you're passing that into the function, your problem is not in the code you've posted.

Also, `warpAffine` is quite slow and unnecessarily general for rotations that are multiples of 90 degrees.  Use flips and transpositions instead, e.g.

```
if (rot == 270) {
    // Rotate clockwise 270 degrees
    Core.flip(mat.t(), mat, 0);
} else if (rot == 180) {
    // Rotate clockwise 180 degrees
    Core.flip(mat, mat, -1);
} else if (rot == 90) {
    // Rotate clockwise 90 degrees
    Core.flip(mat.t(), mat, 1);
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer, you've been very clear. I've tried to use Core.flip instead of warpAffine, but, except in rotations of 180 degrees, it gives me black screen.

Comment: I had the exact same problem.  The reason is that for 90 and 270 degrees, you're transposing the matrix, which changes the size (the number of rows and number of columns are switched).  If you've pre-allocated a bitmap or something that has a fixed size, the size will be wrong for those rotations.  `warpAffine` doesn't have this problem since it compresses the image along one dimension, and stretches it along the other, so that it will fit in the original matrix.

Comment: Look for an exception somewhere like `Utils.MattoBitmap()`.  If you have a try block with an empty catch, make sure you print the exception to the log so that you're not left in the dark the next time this happens.